# Is there any neural network model that can perform multiple NLP steps at once?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing, natural-language-understanding, expert-systems, natural-language-generation

I realize most NLP algorithms have multiple steps. (e.g. OCR/speech rec > syntax > semantics > response logic > semantic output > natural language output)

Is there any NN model that can perform multiple steps in NLP at once? For example, a single network which accepts audio input and returns a semantic analysis of the given speech, or a single network which accepts text input and returns natural language output?

Comment: Is T5 the sort of thing you're looking for? https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/02/exploring-transfer-learning-with-t5.html

Comment: Yes! That's very close to what I had in mind. Do you know of anything similar that is capable of OCR/speech recognition as well?